# Indicate current page on included Nav.php file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to avoid code repetition by including my navigation links as a sperate file across all pages this works fine

But my problem is how to indicate the current page on the nav links i know how to add classes dynamically with JavaScript but i don't know how to go about searching the DOM and finding the current page link and adding a class or style to it.

Example of my nav link is:

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.php" alt="Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.php" alt="About">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php" alt="Contact">Cont.</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

And i included it like so:

```
  <?php include("./nav.php");?>
```

Comment: You could execute a `javascript` function to read the current URL and use that to target the `href` with the matching results from the URL to set a `class`. Since you haven't shown any attempt of achieving this on your own I will only post a comment and not write the source code for you.

Comment: I understand your hint but please what js function do i use to get the URL i can get the <li>herf with `querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');` then use a loop to go through them

Comment: But i don't know how to get the href should i use `.href` and also get the url of the page and strip out all unessary parts keeping only the actual page name which i will use in the loop for comparison

Comment: Here is another hint for you. `console.log(window.location);` You can look at the properties from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following example. Do note that you have `herf` which should be `href`. An `a` tag doesn't have an `alt` attribute, instead use `title`. Also the example uses es6 functions so you need something like babel to make it work with IE.

```js
let currentUrl = window.location.href;
const urls = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('nav a') );

urls.forEach( url => {  
  if( url.getAttribute('href') === currentUrl ) {
    url.classList.add('active')
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: red;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js" title="About">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php" title="Contact">Cont.</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you am always so lost when it comes to structuring JavaScript its hard getting used to coming from c# thanks for the href i always misspell that

Comment: Sure no problem. Using es6 it's way easier to structure JS. TypesScript might also help if you want to look into JS classes

Comment: Don't worry about the es6 syntax i can break it down to basic js i just needed the structure and how to grab on to the url without getting all unessary parts of it. which you've shown me thank you :)